# Still not loading java correctly

Tags: anypoint-studio

I have downloaded both Java 8 and Anypoint Studio. I have tried setting the path to Java, but it never loads.

I keep getting error 13[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV4cB.png)

Comment: have you also set java_home in the environment variables ?

Answer (score 0):

The -vm configuration seems correct. It might be that the Java version used is 64 bits and this version of Studio is 32 bits (I see a library for x86 which indicates 32 bits architecture in the error, it would be x86_64 if it were 64 bits). Studio and Java architecture have to match.